# Open a URL in a new window/active tab

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I know how to open a window in a new tab:

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab();
newTab.url = "http://something"
```

I know how to create a new window: `safari.application.openBrowserWindow();`

How do I open a URL in the newly created window? Or how do I open a URL in the activeBrowerWindow's active tab?

Answer (score 2):

```
var nwin = safari.application.openBrowserWindow();
nwin.activeTab.url = "http://www.example.com";
```